# Conditional Probability

Tags: probability

I'm not liking this at all. Can't even figure a single thing out.

Question

In a $50$ group of people there are $15$ who are lefties and blonde, $15$ neither of them, and $20$ blondes.

A. Draw venn diagram.
B. One is chosen, calculate the probabilities of the person being lefty?
C. One of the lefty is chosen, calculate the probabilites of the person not being blonde?

My answers so far which are completely wrong.

A.

U = 15

$P(A\cup B) = 35$

$P(A\cap B) = 15$ (lefty and blonde)

$P(A)= 20$ (blondes)

$P(B)= 5$ (lefty)

B. No idea, I've tried $15/35 = 3/7$ can't figure out , I've been doing this for $4$ hours literally.

C. Same as $B$.

Comment: In a 50 group of people there are 15 who are lefties and blonde, 15 neither of them, and 20* blondes. 20 BLONDES INSTEAD OF 15

Comment: Correct it **immediately** in the question itself !

Comment: You can edit your question to show any changes: just click 'edit' in the bottom left corner of your question. Also, do the 20 blondes include the 15 who are blondes and lefties?

Comment: Doesn't include who they are, I guess it's only a one gender sided.

Answer (score 0):

Lefties alone:$x$
Lefties & blondes:$15$
Blondes alone: $5$
Neither:$15$

$x = 50 - (15+5+15) = 15$

P(lefty) = $\dfrac5{50}$

P(blonde | lefty) = $\dfrac{15}{15+15}$